# VBA - Objeto InterneExplorer (Frame)

Tags: vba

Preciso acessar uma TAG(a) que está dentro de um Iframe que é carregado em uma mesma pagina após um submit.

Veja que estranho:

- Quando carrego o objeto no código VBA, vejo o Iframe que preciso, mas o HTML que está dentro do Iframe não é carregado no objeto do código VBA.
- É possível realizar uma atualização forçada para o Objeto (HTMLIFrame) carregar todo o html que surge  na pagina após o submit?

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Veja o código:

```
IE.Navigate "https://xxx.xxx"
WaitIE IE
IE.Document.all("ComponentID").innerText = "gem"
Set IEDoc = IE.Document
IE.Document.all("search").form.all("search").Click
WaitIE IE
Set IEDoc = IE.Document


Set profileFrame = IEDoc.getElementById("getPathBuffer") ' getPathBuffer = Nome do Iframe
Set objCollection = profileFrame.getElementsByTagName("a") 'TAG onde está o link que preciso clicar
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name <> "" Then
        MsgBox objCollection(i).Name
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

[image: Imagem VBA]

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1):

troque:

```
Set profileFrame = IEDoc.getElementById("getPathBuffer") ' getPathBuffer = Nome do Iframe
Set objCollection = profileFrame.getElementsByTagName("a") 'TAG onde está o link que preciso clicar
```

por:

```
Set objCollection = ie.Document.frames(0).Document.getElementsByTagName("a") 'o indice numerico é a posição do seu frame**
```

se fui útil, vote na resposta :)